# OPC UA Secure connection in vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, opc-ua

I found an Example code to connect to a UA Server in C#:

```
        Console.WriteLine("Configuring UA Client");
        var config = new ApplicationConfiguration()
        {
            ApplicationName = "OPC_Client_SQL",
            ApplicationUri = Utils.Format(@"urn:{0}:BatchPlantClient", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()),
            ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
            SecurityConfiguration = new SecurityConfiguration
            {
                ApplicationCertificate = new CertificateIdentifier { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault", SubjectName = "OPC_Client_SQL" },
                TrustedIssuerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities" },
                TrustedPeerCertificates = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications" },
                RejectedCertificateStore = new CertificateTrustList { StoreType = @"Directory", StorePath = @"%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates" },
                AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = true
            },
            TransportConfigurations = new TransportConfigurationCollection(),
            TransportQuotas = new TransportQuotas { OperationTimeout = 15000 },
            ClientConfiguration = new ClientConfiguration { DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000 },
            TraceConfiguration = new TraceConfiguration()
        };
        config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        if (config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates)
        {
            config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation += (s, e) => { e.Accept = (e.Error.StatusCode == StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted); };
        }
```

I tried to transfer it in vb.net, but i get an error:

```
   Console.WriteLine("Configuring UA Client")
   Dim config = New ApplicationConfiguration() With {
       .ApplicationName = "OPC_Client_SQL",
       .ApplicationUri = Utils.Format("urn:{0}:OPC_Client_SQL", System.Net.Dns.GetHostName()),
       .ApplicationType = ApplicationType.Client,
       .SecurityConfiguration = New SecurityConfiguration With {
           .ApplicationCertificate = New CertificateIdentifier With {
               .StoreType = "Directory",
               .StorePath = "%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\MachineDefault",
               .SubjectName = "OPC_Client_SQL"
           },
           .TrustedIssuerCertificates = New CertificateTrustList With {
               .StoreType = "Directory",
               .StorePath = "%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Certificate Authorities"
           },
           .TrustedPeerCertificates = New CertificateTrustList With {
               .StoreType = "Directory",
               .StorePath = "%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\UA Applications"
           },
           .RejectedCertificateStore = New CertificateTrustList With {
               .StoreType = "Directory",
               .StorePath = "%CommonApplicationData%\OPC Foundation\CertificateStores\RejectedCertificates"
           },
           .AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates = True
       },
       .TransportConfigurations = New TransportConfigurationCollection(),
       .TransportQuotas = New TransportQuotas With {
           .OperationTimeout = 15000
       },
       .ClientConfiguration = New ClientConfiguration With {
           .DefaultSessionTimeout = 60000
       },
       .TraceConfiguration = New TraceConfiguration()
   }

   config.Validate(ApplicationType.Client).GetAwaiter().GetResult()
   If config.SecurityConfiguration.AutoAcceptUntrustedCertificates Then
       AddHandler config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation, Sub(s, e) e.Accept = e.Error.StatusCode = StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted
   End If
```

Error Line:
AddHandler config.CertificateValidator.CertificateValidation, Sub(s, e) e.Accept = e.Error.StatusCode = StatusCodes.BadCertificateUntrusted

BC36641 - Lambda parameter '' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.

Would be fine if anyone can help me solve this problem.

Comment: The C# snippet has .ApplicationUri = Utils.Format("urn:{0}: **BatchPlantClient**" ... while your VB.NET code reads .ApplicationUri = Utils.Format("urn:{0}: **OPC_Client_SQL**" ... Not sure if that makes a difference though.